# How I can find all files that corresponds to pattern like .gitignore

Tags: files, grep, find

So for example. I have a file like `.myignore`. In that file, I have strings like:

```
.vs/
*.suo
*.user
*.log
```

Then I want to find all files that match to the pattern in file `.myignore`.

Comment: Do you also want to take the _special_ semantics of `.gitignore` files into account, like matching patterns starting with `/` from the directory where the `.gitignore` file is located, patterns starting with `#` are ignored like comments, `!` negates patterns, using `**` matches across `/` in pathnames, etc. ?

Comment: @they I think no, I just want to find files that match simple pattern then I want to move them in `rm -f` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `zsh`:

```
() {print -rC1 -- ${(u)@}} ${~^${(f)"$(<.gitignore)"}}(ND)
```

Where:

- `() {body} args` is an anonymous function invocation with its arguments
- `print -rC1 -- ${(u)@}` being the body of the function `print`s `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn its `u`nique arguments (`u` flag removes duplicates). Replace `print -rC1` with `rm -rf` if you want to remove those files / directories instead.
- `"$(<.gitignore)"` expands to the contents of `.gitignore` minus the trailing newline characters if any. The quotes being to prevent IFS splitting.
- `${(f)param}` splits the parameter expansion on line`f`eeds (aka newline).
- `${~param}` enables globbing on the resulting words
- `${^array}text` expands the array in a rc-like or fish-like fashion where if `$array` contains `A` and `B` for instance, that expands to `Atext` `Btext` instead of `A` `Btext`.
- `(ND)` adds the `[N]ullglob` and `[D]otglob` qualifiers so hidden files are not skipped and failed matches don't cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array with `IFS` set to newline:

```bsh
# save IFS variable
OLD_IFS=$IFS

# Set IFS to newline only
IFS=$'\n'

# Expand the files to an array.
files=($(<.myignore))

# reset IFS to old value
IFS=$OLD_IFS

# delete your files (remove the echo if the output is ok)
# ... or do other stuff
echo rm -f "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: That assumes ksh93 or bash (or zsh in ksh emulation). You'd also need `FIGNORE='.:..'` (ksh93) or `shopt -s dotglob` (bash), or `set -o dotglob` in `zsh`. Also note that for those words that don't contain wildcard characters, it would print them regardless of whether corresponding files exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply allow the shell expansion to occur by command substitution:

```
echo $(cat .myignore)
ls -ld $(cat .myignore)
rm -rf $(cat .myignore)
```